# OpenCV SuperResolution OutputArray frame

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, opencv3.0

In the documentation for [SuperResolution](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/superres/doc/super_resolution.html)

The code required to output the nextframe is :

 `void superres::SuperResolution::nextFrame(OutputArray frame)`

The input frame source has to be set with :

`void superres::SuperResolution::setInput(const Ptr<FrameSource>& frameSource)`

I have a code that takes frames from a video :

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "iostream"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap ( "video1.mp4" ); // open the default camera
    if( ! cap.isOpened () )  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    /* Mat edges; */
    namedWindow ( "Video" , 1 );
    double frnb ( cap.get ( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT ) );
    std::cout << "frame count = " << frnb << endl;

    for(;;) 
    {
        Mat frame;
        double fIdx;

        std::cout << "frame index ? ";
        std::cin >> fIdx;
        if ( fIdx < 0 || fIdx >= frnb ) break;
        cap.set ( CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES , fIdx );
        bool success = cap.read(frame); 
        if ( ! success ) 
        {
            cout << "Cannot read  frame " << endl;
            break;
        }
        /* cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera */
        imshow("Video", frame);
        if ( waitKey (0) == 27 ) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Given this I can use the `frame` variable as the parameter for the `setInput` method, but how can I initialize the `OutputArray frame` needed to generate the output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you cannot use `frame` as the parameter for the `setInput` and you don't need to initalize the `OutputArray frame`.

Check [this example](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/gpu/super_resolution.cpp) out:

FrameSource is created like this:

```
   121. frameSource = createFrameSource_Video(inputVideoName);
```

And then the outputArray frame is used like this:

```
   142. Mat result; // no intialization, just declaration
   144. MEASURE_TIME(superRes->nextFrame(result));
```